# Lead() considering where clause, don't want it to

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a simple log table named TaskLog.  I want to see how long a certain step is taking by looking at the time difference between that step and the one after.

The query below has the effect of looking at the time between rows that read 'performing media relations rollup' - I don't want the LEAD() rows to follow the WHERE clause. (they should take the next row in cteTask regardless of the value of Notes.

```
;with cteTask as
    (select * from Tasklog where prog = 'StatsMajor' and Date>'8/1/2014')
, cteLead as
    (select *
        , LEAD(ID) over (order by ID) NextID
        , LEAD(date) over (order by ID) NextDt

    from cteTask 
    where notes = 'performing media relations rollup'
    )
select *, DATEDIFF(second, Date, NextDt) as Secs
from cteLead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter after?

```
;with cteTask as
    (select * from Tasklog where prog = 'StatsMajor' and Date>'8/1/2014')
, cteLead as
    (select *
        , LEAD(ID) over (order by ID) NextID
        , LEAD(date) over (order by ID) NextDt

    from cteTask 
    )
select *, DATEDIFF(second, Date, NextDt) as Secs
from cteLead
where notes = 'performing media relations rollup'
```

Comment: this works but the LEAD/LAG syntax isn't intuitive to me.  I'm sure I'll get burned by it often (just upgraded to 2014 this week from 2008).